# File management- preventing the deletion of files referenced by nodes

Tags: 8, files, media

I'm not a Drupal user normally but a client wants to move from a 200 page flat file site managed in DreamWeaver to a Drupal site.

Issue is that their secretarial staff who have been managing the site in DW want Drupal 8 to warn them before they delete a media file referenced by Drupal nodes.  This is for them primarily images and PDFs which they intend to add to the server via FTP.

Can anyone direct me to a module that provides either that warning functionality or a list of nodes referencing media and PDF files?

Comment: @kiamlaluno where on SO would this be "on topic"?  Since Drupal core is not intended to solve this problem am I simply not allowed on SO to seek a module-based solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is for them primarily images and PDFs which they intend to add to the server via FTP.

No... I would advise installing the [Media Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) and set of modules designed for handling media.

This will allow you to add media in a way that has better treatment than core. You will be able to:

- Use one file in multiple places without uploading it again
- Build displays based around media, if you need to
- Add a button in CKEditor for referencing or uploading new media

If you only upload files in an FTP, you *can't* do basic things, like:

- Resize an image with an image style
- See how many times / where an image or file is being used
- Generate different displays for different files
- Create Views based around media which may be mixed with access grants later on (spitballing)

Core upload fields, or FTP copying, will not grant you anything - and giving non technical people access to FTP instead of a GUI backend like Drupal is far more error prone.

Also, there is a known core issue where files can be deleted without warning, and it is suggested to set the core file system setting of "Delete orphaned files after.." to "**Never**". No matter how you choose to approach media management, change this setting ASAP until it is fixed.

One of the major benefits of moving from a static setup to Drupal 8 are for reasons like this.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal provides a huge number of excellent features, but managing your FTP interaction with the server is not one of them.

When moving an organization from DreamWeaver to Drupal (or any good CMS for that matter) you need to have a real change strategy that helps them understand they can't just keep doing what they do now. They need to totally interact with Drupal in the ways you setup for them, and not try to bring over any of their existing tools or habits. Even when that is possible it will cause more problems than it solves because they don't embrace the change, and value, of the CMS.

Drupal 8 core does track files that uploaded through fields or CKEditor so it can clean up when they are no longer referenced. You can also add the [editor file module](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_file) to provide a good single file linking field (instead of uploading through imce and using an interface optimized for images). The [Editor Advanced Link module](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link) also provides some useful extensions.